# Matplotlib "gray" colormap doesn't span full black to white range

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, grayscale

The following code produces a circular pattern:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp

def sphere_depth(x, y, depth, radius):
  squ = x**2 + y**2
  rsqu = radius**2
  squ[squ > rsqu] = rsqu
  res = np.sqrt(rsqu - squ)
  res -= (radius - depth)
  res[res < 0.] = 0.
  return res

y_pix = x_pix = 100.

c_steps = 10

x, y = np.mgrid[0:x_pix:1, 0:y_pix:1]
z = sphere_depth(x - x_pix / 2, y - y_pix / 2, 5., 100.)
lvls = np.linspace(z.min(), z.max(), c_steps)

mp.close(1)
fig = mp.figure(1)
mp.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
mp.contourf(x, y, z, cmap=mp.cm.gray, levels=lvls)
mp.axis('off')
mp.savefig("test.png")
```

The colormap is set to "gray" and I expect that the minimum value corresponds to black and the maximum value to white. While the later is true, the former doesn't hold for this example. The lowest value is rather dark gray. This can be adjusted when increasing `c_steps`, but I need to have a very coarse grained gray color map. Thanks for any ideas how to start with a black color and end with white.

Comment: Change `lvls` to something like 100. YOu only have 10 levels. So the colormap will only shown those 10 levels.

Comment: That's on purpose, as I explained in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contourf` behaves a bit differently than `imshow` or `pcolormesh` in this case.  It's deliberate for consistency with `contour`, and due to the way the levels are defined.

The color for each level range is defined by the midpoint of that range.  (Also, your center contour isn't actually completely white, but it's visually identical to it.)

To specify that you want the first interval filled with "pure" black, set `vmin=mean(lvls[:1])` in your example.

As an example, based on your excellent example in your question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sphere_depth(x, y, depth, radius):
  squ = x**2 + y**2
  rsqu = radius**2
  squ[squ > rsqu] = rsqu
  res = np.sqrt(rsqu - squ)
  res -= (radius - depth)
  res[res < 0.] = 0.
  return res

y_pix = x_pix = 100.

c_steps = 10

x, y = np.mgrid[0:x_pix:1, 0:y_pix:1]
z = sphere_depth(x - x_pix / 2, y - y_pix / 2, 5., 100.)
lvls = np.linspace(z.min(), z.max(), c_steps)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
ax.contourf(x, y, z, levels=lvls, cmap=plt.cm.gray, 
            vmin=np.mean(lvls[:2]), vmax=np.mean(lvls[-2:]))
ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Just for comparison, here's the image from your original example:

[image]

It's subtle, but the first one has "pure" black at the edges, and the second one doesn't.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks a lot. However, with your code I can't reproduce the image you posted. In fact, when comparing an image with `vmin=np.mean(lvls[:1]), vmax=np.mean(lvls[-2:])` and without that line, the image **without** has a slightly darker background.

Comment: @Clemens - Sorry about that, I changed a couple of things and didn't re-run the code and a typo crept in.  `lvls[:1]` is a typo. It should be `vmin=np.mean(lvls[:2])`.